# Uploading Image from iPhone to Server (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net, nsmutableurlrequest

I'm trying to upload an from an iPhone to a remote server using ASP.Net. But I can't get it to work. Things get stranger because this code worked two days ago. WTF?

Here is the ASP.Net Code:

```
public partial class UploadPhoto : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files.Count > 0 ? Request.Files[0] : null;

            String filename = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
            String[] names = file.FileName.Split('.');
            string src = filename + "." + names[names.Length - 1];

            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + src);
            Response.Write("Success");
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.Output.Write("Failure");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Objective C Code:

```
-(IBAction)UploadPhoto:(id)sender{ 

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ImageView.image); 
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@UploadPhoto.aspx", URL]; 


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; 
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]; 
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData]; 
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO]; 
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"; 
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary]; 
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"]; 

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data]; 
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"image.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]]; 
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 

    [request setHTTPBody:body]; 

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 

    NSLog(@"%@", returnString); 
}
```

Does anyone know why this is not working? I've looked at other snippets of code, literally copy/pasting the code in, but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Son of a ....

It was the server all along.

The page request would redirect cause all the POST data to disappear.

All I had to do was remove the **".aspx"** from URL and it worked.

**Link:** http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/26394-cannot-http-post-to-server-returns-empty-post.html